# Как работать с cookies

Tags: android, cookie, httpclient

Добрый день. 
Есть сайт на который с помощью `HttpClient` я отправляю `get` и `post` запросы,

```
 public String doGet(String url) {
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(client.getParams(), "My funcy UA");

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, localContext);
        System.out.println("Response Code:" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        Header[] cookiesArray = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");

        for (int i = 0; i < cookiesArray.length; i++) {
            Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(cookiesArray[i].getName().toString(), cookiesArray[i].getValue()
                    .toString());
            cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
        }

        System.out.println();

        List<Cookie> cookieList = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookieList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Cookie " + "name :  " + cookieList.get(i).getName() + "   value :"
                    + cookieList.get(i).getValue());
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

В теле каждого `get` запроса я получаю `cookies` и кладу их в `CookieStore`. Вопрос в том, как правильно управлять ими? Должен ли я сам смотреть с какими cookies должен посылаться очередной запрос и удалять лишние из `CookieStore`? Или я собираю все пришедшие cookies с каждого запроса и  перехожу c ними к следующему?

Спасибо.

Comment: Экземпляры client и cookieStore каких классов?

Answer (score 1):

> Должен ли я сам смотреть с какими cookies должен посылаться очередной запрос

Я передаю куки просто:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(mUrl);

httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", "chbx=guest; jurl="+jurl+"; ucss=normal; bbuserid="+bbuserid+"; bbpassword="+bbpassword+"; bbusername="+bbusername);            
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

`bbuserid, bbusername` и т.д. - беру из куков, собранных ранее

Comment: ок, что так передавать кукисы мы знаем, а как вы их храните после закрытия приложения? 
Я пытался разобраться с CookieManager и CookieSyncManager, но у меня не получилось понять, как правильно работать с этим механизмом.